# Unable to create new user in mysql for version 5.7

Tags: mysql, syntax, mysql-error-1064, mysql-5.7

I am trying to create a new mysql user say, `user1` with password `password123` using the syntax `CREATE USER 'user1' @ 'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password1';`.

I have checked the documentation for MySQL 5.7 and used the syntax accordingly, still, it doesn't seem to work for me.

I have used the `sudo mysql` command at the terminal to connect to the MySQL server. What am I doing wrong?

Documentation for MySQL 5.7:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html

Comment: Is the user account you have used has privilege to create more account?

Comment: Yes. It is the root user.

Comment: What does "it doesn't seem to work for me" mean? Do you get an error message? Then post it. Does it work without an error, but the new user is not added/cannot log in/...? Then describe this. Also, it might be just a copy&paste effect, but you have spaces around your `@` (which is not allowed).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone landing here, the issue with the above is the spaces on either side of the '@' sign. This will work:

CREATE USER 'user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password1';